# Iterm2 Automatic Profile Switching for Local Directories

Tags: iterm2

I want iterm2 to display local badge names when I switch directories. For example, in the '~/dir_1' directory, I want to display the name 'dir_1' etc.

So far, I have created a new profile:
General section - put 'dir_1' in the badge field and selected 'Home Directory' as the Working Directory Option. 
Advanced section - I am having trouble figuring out the formatting - I've tried iterations of ...
"/Users/erica.dohring/dir_1"
"~/dir_1" 
without the quotes, etc

Could someone provide guidance as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a reasonably old question, but google led me here for a similar question (how to change background color based on directory).

Was able to make this work by creating a couple of profiles, then using the equivalent of the `pwd` in the Preferences>Advanced>Automatic Profile Switching list, i.e. `/Users/ted_foss/workspace/` or, for all sub-dirs under that, `/Users/ted_foss/workspace/*` .